# aligning my image and text in two columns not working

Tags: css

```
<img id="story_image" src="images/builder_story_side.png" alt="photo"/>

<div id="story_right">
<h2 class="story_header">fdgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg</h2>
<p class="small_story">fdgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
</div>



img#story_image{float:left;}

div#story_right{float:left;}
```

I've done two columns before, but for some reason this time it's not working. I want the image to be in column one and the text in column two. Story_right ends up below the image as if story_image was a block.

Comment: Could you make an image of what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly float elements, you need to set a width on the elements that you want to float. Set pixel and dynamic percentage widths can both be used. The reason that this is giving you problems is because the default width of a div is 100%, so the image can't float next to it.

Comment: ah ok "properly." I guess it has been working in the past because I got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it setting widths.

**CSS**

```
#story_image{width: 50%;float:left;}
#story_right{width: 50%;float:left;}
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nnU26/1/